# How to keep database connections to minimum?

Tags: php, android, web-services

I have an android app which is communicating with the database over web service and http web requests. My web service consists of some PHP scripts. Due to the fact that I am storing informations to database every 5-10 seconds, my app becomes very slow. Now, my question is how can I keep database connections to minimum (what should I be looking for) since I know that most of the time in working with database  is spent on connecting to it.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can't you store the information in your android app and send batches in a larger interval?

Comment: Actually I would recommend using a queuing system, then run php as a CLI job ( bypassing apache ), then you can make your workers in the queue persistent, and they will use only one connection.  It's not trivial to setup.

Comment: What do you think about using `mysql_pconnect()` function in my PHP scripts? Will it remain database connections open?

Answer (score 1):

You could basically bulk insert. So instead of sending new request every 5-10 seconds you could still gather data on client side and than send request every 60 seconds or longer. Possibly more than few minutes and on app close.

Comment: Maybe I can send data every few minutes but generally informations from database will be observed in time.

Comment: Than you need to store current data you gather in an object/array and than push it on interval basis.